# JQuery Toggle with Link

Tags: jquery, html, css

When using the jQuery "pulsate" effect, and there is a link in the targeted div, the link is inoperable. How can I prevent the slider effect from running, but instead make it possible to click on a link, and load the target, that is inside the "pulsate" div?

Here is a code example:

```
$(document).ready(function() {  
    $(".toggler").click(function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        $(this).effect('pulsate',{times:2},function(){
            $(this).fadeOut('slow');
        });
    });
});


<div class="aeast toggler">
    <table class="" width="100%">
          <tr>
            <th><img src="http://content.sportslogos.net/logos/7/151/thumbs/y71myf8mlwlk8lbgagh3fd5e0.gif" alt="Patriots"></th>
            <th><img src="http://content.sportslogos.net/logos/7/152/thumbs/v7tehkwthrwefgounvi7znf5k.gif" alt="Jets"></th>
            <th><img src="http://content.sportslogos.net/logos/7/150/thumbs/15041052013.gif" alt="Dolphins"></th>
            <th><img src="http://content.sportslogos.net/logos/7/149/thumbs/n0fd1z6xmhigb0eej3323ebwq.gif" alt="Bills"></th>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td class="name">New England Patriots</td>
            <td>asdad</td>
            <td>dasd</td>
            <td>asd</td>                            
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td><a href="http://www.google.com" target="_blank">Main Website</a></td>
            <td>asda</td>
            <td>asda</td>
            <td>asda</td>                               
          </tr>                       
    </table>                    
</div>
```

See http://jsfiddle.net/zuE65/

Answer (score 1):

You're preventing the default action in your click handler. You can avoid doing that for the link:

http://jsfiddle.net/7xb2V/

```
if (event.target.tagName.toLower() == 'a') return;
```

Or

```
if ($(event.target).is('a')) return;
```

You could also bind a second handler to the `a` and `stopPropagation`:

http://jsfiddle.net/25sQs/

```
$('.toggler a').click(function(e) {
   e.stopPropagation(); 
});
```

Comment: Thanks man, I knew it had something to do with the a functioning. I just didn't know how to go about building the code in the javascript.